# Problem with Lumia 920 and Macbook

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, macos

I'm trying to sync my iTunes library with Lumia 920 (using the windows phone app) but my macbook doesn't recoginize the phone. I already tested the usb ports (even with another Lumia, and the WP App recognized it), and I can sync the 920 on windows 7. My macbook just don't recognize MY phone. Does anybody knows why?

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable, or a different USB port on your Mac?

Comment: Yep. Tried all ports and different usb cables. This cable works well when I connect a Lumia 820, but my 920 don't.

Comment: Did you install the windows phone app?

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows phone app

Comment: Are the running OS X Mavericks (10.9) with all the updates?

Comment: All softwares up to date (mavericks, windows app and the software in the phone).